# Exp:resso Store - price for additional items

Tags: add-on, ee2, expresso-store

I'm using Exp:resso Store for the first time, and I've just set-up my shipping method and its rules. 
I've created a standard shipping method that includes different countries - this was fairly easy. 
The problem is that I cannot find a way to add 1,00 GBP only to additional items.

I tried creating different rules:

- if min. Order qty and max. Order qty is 1 then there's no additional
  rate
- if min. Order qty is 2 then add the additional rate

but in this way if there's more than 1 item then Store adds 1,00 GBP to all items, while I need it to be added to all items *except* the first one.

I just don't understand if this can be achieved by playing with shipping rules or if I need some custom plug-in. 
As I said I've never used Store before, every suggestion would be much appreciated.

---

### Edit

I might add that I have a base rate of 2.50 £:

- Base shipping rate for UK: 2.50 £
- Shipping rate for additional items (except 1st): 1,00 £

This means that if the customer buys one item total shipping cost would be only 2,50 £ for the shipping.

If the customer buys 2 items, then total shipping cost would be 2,50 + 1,00 = 3,50 £ for the shipping.

For 3 items the total shipping cost would be 4,50£ (that is 2,50 + 1,00 + 1,00). And so on.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question to Exp:resso Store official support and they confirmed that having a rule that sets a base rate + an additional shipping rate free for the first item is not possible without writing some custom PHP.

Anyhow they suggested to lower base rate to 1.50£ and let Store add the additional rate (1£) to every item:

- 1 product = 1.50 + 1.00 = 2.50
- 2 products = 1.50 + 2.00 = 3.50
- 3 products = 1.50 + 3.00 = 4.50

As you can see the end result would be the same.

I hope the solution suggested by Exp:resso staff will be useful for someone else!